# String comparison returns False for same strings

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, string-comparison

I have a simple piece of code I run in Unity:

```
string cmd = inputField.text;

foreach (var command in _commands)
{
    Debug.Log("." + command.commandPattern + ".");
    Debug.Log("." + cmd + ".");
    Debug.Log(String.Equals(command.commandPattern.ToString(), cmd.ToString()));

}
```

`_commands` is a list of `Command` objects and it contains one `ResetCommand` which inherits from `Command`. Here are the classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Command
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string commandPattern;

    public void Execute() { }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResetCommand : Command
{
    public ResetCommand()
    {
        commandPattern = "reset";
    }

    public new void Execute()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}
```

After running the code the Unity Console output looks like this:

[image: Unity Console]

The comparison doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of a debugger.

[image: scr]

Comment: Have you tried printing out the ascii/hex code and compare these? `Debug.Log(BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cmd));`

Comment: And why do you `ToString` if these are already strings?

Comment: @derHugo you are right, the `cmd` variable has extra `E2-80-8B` at the end. Ant idea why it's there and how to get rid of that?

Comment: [Simplest way to get rid of zero-width-space in c# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942167/simplest-way-to-get-rid-of-zero-width-space-in-c-sharp-string)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, it works! If you want to add an answer for me to accept then go ahead.